# Issue with displaying todo form and updating todoform in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, crud

I currently am creating a todo app in react and I am able to create and delete the todolist
But I am having issues with updating the list with a new todo
when I click on the update button which is in the todo.jsx I want it to display the form that I have created
and then be able to display the new list. I sort of have it working properly but the only thing that works is it will display every item in the list as a form instead of just the one item that needs to be updated. I would like assistance in learning how to work out this issue. I don't know if I need to pass down the function and map it out to test if the item is equal to the id that is passed in after clicking on update. whenever I do this I can't get the newlist to display instead I can console.log it out but its not rendering to the page.

This is my app.jsx

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import ToDoForm from './Components/ToDoForm'
import ToDoList from './Components/ToDoList'
import Update from './Components/Update'
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid'
import './style.css'

export default function App() {

  
  const [todoItems, setTodoItems] = useState([])
  const [updateForm, setUpdateForm] = useState(false)
  
  
  const createTodo = (todo) => {
    setTodoItems(prev => [...prev, {
      id:uuid(),
      task: todo,
      completed: false,
      progress: "0%",
      priority: "low",
      date: new Date().toDateString(),
    }])
  }

  const deleteTodo = (id) => {
    const newTodoItems = todoItems.filter(item => item.id !== id)
    setTodoItems(newTodoItems)
  }

  const handleUpdate = (id) => {
    todoItems.map(item => {
      if(item.id === id) {
        setUpdateForm(prev => !prev)
        return <Update />
      }
    })
  }
  
  const updateTodo = (id, newValue) => {
    console.log(id, newValue)
  }

  

  return (
    <main>
      <ToDoForm 
        createTodo={createTodo}
      />
      
      <ToDoList 
        todos={todoItems}
        deleteTodo={deleteTodo}
        updateTodo={updateTodo}
        handleUpdate={handleUpdate}
        updateForm={updateForm}
      />
    </main>
      
  )
}
```

This is my TODOLIST

```
import React from 'react';
import ToDo from './ToDo';
import Update from './Update'
export default function ToDoList({todos,deleteTodo,handleUpdate,updateForm}) {   
  
  const displayToDos = todos.map(todo => (

    <ToDo 
      key={todo.id}
      id={todo.id}
      task={todo.task}
      deleteTodo={deleteTodo}
      handleUpdate={handleUpdate}
      todos={todos}
    />
  ));
  return (
    <div>
      {todos && displayToDos} 
      {updateForm && <Update />}
    </div>
  )
  
}
```

This is my Todo

```
import React from 'react'

export default function ToDo({task,id,deleteTodo,handleUpdate}) {

  
  return (
    <>
      <p>{task}</p>
      {task && <button onClick={() => handleUpdate(id)}>Update</button>}
      {task && <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(id)}>Delete</button>} 
    </>
  )
}
```

This is my Update form

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ToDo from './ToDo'
export default function Update({id,updateTodo}) {

  const [newValue, setNewValue] = useState("");

  const handleEdit = (event) => {
    setNewValue(event.target.value)
  }

  const handleUpdate = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    updateTodo(id,newValue)
  }

  return (
    <>
        <form onSubmit={handleUpdate}>
          <input 
            type="text" 
            value={newValue}
            placeholder="update task" 
            required
            onChange={handleEdit}
          /> 
          <button type="submit">Update</button>
        </form>
    </>
  )
}
```

I tried to render the form in place of the todo
and I tried rendering just the form and the other todos.
I also tried creating another todolist.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

First thing, your Update component expects an id and an updateTodo function to be passed as props and in both cases the component is used there are no props passed.

```
 {updateForm && <Update />}
```

and

```
  todoItems.map(item => {
      if(item.id === id) {
        setUpdateForm(prev => !prev)
        return <Update />
      }
    })
```

Now, the map iteration is not really working because the map function returns a new version of the array not changing the array itself,so the only thing that's happening is toggling the updateForm variable. Also the array variable is a state variable so you can only change it using the assigned setState function : `setTodoItems`

If I understand correctly you want to change the text of a todo in the Update component, you could achieve this by creating a new state variable to keep the id of the todo you want update and pass that to the Update component , something like this:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import ToDoForm from './Components/ToDoForm'
import ToDoList from './Components/ToDoList'
import Update from './Components/Update'
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid'
import './style.css'

export default function App() {

  
  const [todoItems, setTodoItems] = useState([])
  const [updateForm, setUpdateForm] = useState(false)
  const [todoIdToUpdate, setTodoIdToUpdate] = useState(null)
  
  const createTodo = (todo) => {
    setTodoItems(prev => [...prev, {
      id:uuid(),
      task: todo,
      completed: false,
      progress: "0%",
      priority: "low",
      date: new Date().toDateString(),
    }])
  }

  const deleteTodo = (id) => {
    const newTodoItems = todoItems.filter(item => item.id !== id)
    setTodoItems(newTodoItems)
  }

  const handleUpdate = (id) => {
    setTodoIdToUpdate(id);
    setUpdateForm(prev => !prev) // or you could just set it true here
  }
  
  const updateTodo = (id, newValue) => {
    console.log(id, newValue)
  }

  

  return (
    <main>
      <ToDoForm 
        createTodo={createTodo}
      />
      
      <ToDoList 
        todos={todoItems}
        deleteTodo={deleteTodo}
        updateTodo={updateTodo}
        handleUpdate={handleUpdate}
        updateForm={updateForm}
        todoIdToUpdate={todoIdToUpdate}
      />
    </main>
      
  )
}
```

With the id of the todo you want to update in your list component now you can pass it to the Update component, or even change the logic of the component and pass the todo itself if you want.

Comment: Hello David, ok so the setUpdate form is to show when I click on the update button for the specific item, the updateTodo is to map through the original array and set the new name of the item in the array item. The issue that keeps on happening after I implemented your solution was that it was showing an input form for every item instead of the single item after clicking on the update button. the save button is to show the new version of the todolist.  When you say that the update component needs props I passed in the props but the Update component does not have props like id to pass.

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding what exactly do you want to achieve, can you please go over again how exactly do you want this app to behave?